# Plotting 2 windroses side by side

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a image with 2 side-by-side windroses (windrose function by clifro library)

```
library(clifro)
library(tidyverse)

winddata <- read_csv('../Desktop/demo_mast.csv')

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
windrose(speed = winddata$SPD_59_COMB_AVG,
     direction = winddata$DIR_80_AVG,
     speed_cuts = seq(0,25,5),
     legend_title="Vel [m/s]",
     ggtheme='minimal')+labs(title=paste0("Windvane 80m"))
windrose(speed = winddata$SPD_47_COMB_AVG,
     direction = winddata$DIR_95_AVG,
     speed_cuts = seq(0,25,5),
     legend_title="Vel [m/s]",
     ggtheme='minimal')+labs(title=paste0("Windvane 95m"))

par(windroses)
```

demo_mast.csv is from a [kaggle tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/srlightfoote/example-wind-analysis-in-r)

I've tried using par function, but it seems to display plots separately

Desired output:

[image: Windroses plots]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this issue by using **grid.arrange** function from **gridExtra** library:

```
library(clifro)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

winddata <- read_csv('../Desktop/demo_mast.csv')

wr1 <- windrose(speed = winddata$SPD_59_COMB_AVG,
  direction = winddata$DIR_80_AVG,
  speed_cuts = seq(0,25,5),
  legend_title="Vel [m/s]",
  ggtheme='minimal')+labs(title=paste0("Windvane 80m"))
wr2 <- windrose(speed = winddata$SPD_47_COMB_AVG,
  direction = winddata$DIR_95_AVG,
  speed_cuts = seq(0,25,5),
  legend_title="Vel [m/s]",
  ggtheme='minimal')+labs(title=paste0("Windvane 95m"))

windr <- grid.arrange(wr1,wr2,ncol=2)
ggsave(file="windrose.png", plot=windr, device="png", path='../Desktop/', height=4, width=8)
```